# Datatable Server Side Pagination For AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, pagination, datatables

I am building a web-app with datatables. I get data from an api and it has server side pagination. I want to implement that pagination to my datatable and gonna need your help :)

Here is my datatable's js code:

```
        $http({
            url: "http://localhost/standarts-and-partners-api/documents",
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
        }).then(function (response) {

            $scope.documents = response.data.data;

            $timeout(function () {
                // Init full DataTable, for more examples you can check out https://www.datatables.net/
                var initDataTableFull = function () {
                    jQuery('.js-dataTable-full').dataTable();
                };

                // DataTables Bootstrap integration
                var bsDataTables = function () {
                    var DataTable = jQuery.fn.dataTable;

                    // Set the defaults for DataTables init
                    jQuery.extend(true, DataTable.defaults, {
                        dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-6'l><'col-sm-6'f>>" +
                        "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
                        "<'row'<'col-sm-6'i><'col-sm-6'p>>",
                        renderer: 'bootstrap',
                        oLanguage: {
                            sLengthMenu: "_MENU_",
                            sInfo: "Showing <strong>_START_</strong>-<strong>_END_</strong> of <strong>_TOTAL_</strong>",
                            oPaginate: {
                                sPrevious: '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>',
                                sNext: '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>'
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    // Default class modification
                    jQuery.extend(DataTable.ext.classes, {
                        sWrapper: "dataTables_wrapper form-inline dt-bootstrap",
                        sFilterInput: "form-control",
                        sLengthSelect: "form-control"
                    });

                    // Bootstrap paging button renderer
                    DataTable.ext.renderer.pageButton.bootstrap = function (settings, host, idx, buttons, page, pages) {
                        var api = new DataTable.Api(settings);
                        var classes = settings.oClasses;
                        var lang = settings.oLanguage.oPaginate;
                        var btnDisplay, btnClass;

                        var attach = function (container, buttons) {
                            var i, ien, node, button;
                            var clickHandler = function (e) {
                                e.preventDefault();
                                if (!jQuery(e.currentTarget).hasClass('disabled')) {
                                    api.page(e.data.action).draw(false);
                                }
                            };

                            for (i = 0, ien = buttons.length; i < ien; i++) {
                                button = buttons[i];

                                if (jQuery.isArray(button)) {
                                    attach(container, button);
                                }
                                else {
                                    btnDisplay = '';
                                    btnClass = '';

                                    switch (button) {
                                        case 'ellipsis':
                                            btnDisplay = '&hellip;';
                                            btnClass = 'disabled';
                                            break;

                                        case 'first':
                                            btnDisplay = lang.sFirst;
                                            btnClass = button + (page > 0 ? '' : ' disabled');
                                            break;

                                        case 'previous':
                                            btnDisplay = lang.sPrevious;
                                            btnClass = button + (page > 0 ? '' : ' disabled');
                                            break;

                                        case 'next':
                                            btnDisplay = lang.sNext;
                                            btnClass = button + (page < pages - 1 ? '' : ' disabled');
                                            break;

                                        case 'last':
                                            btnDisplay = lang.sLast;
                                            btnClass = button + (page < pages - 1 ? '' : ' disabled');
                                            break;

                                        default:
                                            btnDisplay = button + 1;
                                            btnClass = page === button ?
                                                'active' : '';
                                            break;
                                    }

                                    if (btnDisplay) {
                                        node = jQuery('<li>', {
                                            'class': classes.sPageButton + ' ' + btnClass,
                                            'aria-controls': settings.sTableId,
                                            'tabindex': settings.iTabIndex,
                                            'id': idx === 0 && typeof button === 'string' ?
                                                settings.sTableId + '_' + button :
                                                null
                                        })
                                            .append(jQuery('<a>', {
                                                    'href': '#'
                                                })
                                                    .html(btnDisplay)
                                            )
                                            .appendTo(container);

                                        settings.oApi._fnBindAction(
                                            node, {action: button}, clickHandler
                                        );
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        };

                        attach(
                            jQuery(host).empty().html('<ul class="pagination"/>').children('ul'),
                            buttons
                        );
                    };

                    // TableTools Bootstrap compatibility - Required TableTools 2.1+
                    if (DataTable.TableTools) {
                        // Set the classes that TableTools uses to something suitable for Bootstrap
                        jQuery.extend(true, DataTable.TableTools.classes, {
                            "container": "DTTT btn-group",
                            "buttons": {
                                "normal": "btn btn-default",
                                "disabled": "disabled"
                            },
                            "collection": {
                                "container": "DTTT_dropdown dropdown-menu",
                                "buttons": {
                                    "normal": "",
                                    "disabled": "disabled"
                                }
                            },
                            "print": {
                                "info": "DTTT_print_info"
                            },
                            "select": {
                                "row": "active"
                            }
                        });

                        // Have the collection use a bootstrap compatible drop down
                        jQuery.extend(true, DataTable.TableTools.DEFAULTS.oTags, {
                            "collection": {
                                "container": "ul",
                                "button": "li",
                                "liner": "a"
                            }
                        });
                    }
                };

                // Init Datatables
                bsDataTables();
                initDataTableFull();

            });
```

And this is the json data that i get from the api:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "description": "Bu ekledigimiz ilk belge, hayirli olsun.",
      "due_date": "16.03.2017",
      "company_id": 2,
      "department_id": 2,
      "reason_id": 1,
      "group_order_id": 1,
      "status": 1,
      "created_by": 4,
      "created": "06.04.2017",
      "modified": "20.04.2017",
      "approved_by": "Kivanc Bey",
      "deleted": null,
      "document_images": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "document_id": 1,
          "folder_path": "/deneme/2/",
          "file_name": "5.png",
          "created": "08.04.2017",
          "deleted": null
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "document_id": 1,
          "folder_path": "/deneme/2/",
          "file_name": "8.png",
          "created": "08.04.2017",
          "deleted": null
        }
      ],
      "company": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Media Markt",
        "code": "MMM",
        "contact_user_id": 1,
        "manager_id": 4,
        "created_by": 2,
        "created": "16.03.2017",
        "modified": "19.04.2017",
        "deleted": null
      },
      "user": {
        "id": 4,
        "role_id": 11,
        "cell_phone": null,
        "first_name": "Burak",
        "last_name": "Ozturk",
        "created": "16.03.2017",
        "modified": null,
        "token_expire": null,
        "deleted": null
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "description": "Technology expenditure",
      "due_date": "16.03.2017",
      "company_id": 1,
      "department_id": 2,
      "reason_id": 3,
      "group_order_id": 3,
      "status": 1,
      "created_by": 4,
      "created": "08.04.2017",
      "modified": "20.04.2017",
      "approved_by": "Kivanc Bey",
      "deleted": null,
      "document_images": [],
      "company": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Facebook",
        "code": "FB",
        "contact_user_id": 2,
        "manager_id": 3,
        "created_by": 3,
        "created": "16.03.2017",
        "modified": "27.03.2017",
        "deleted": null
      },
      "user": {
        "id": 4,
        "role_id": 11,
        "cell_phone": null,
        "first_name": "Burak",
        "last_name": "Ozturk",
        "created": "16.03.2017",
        "modified": null,
        "token_expire": null,
        "deleted": null
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "description": "Two computer has bought",
      "due_date": "16.03.2017",
      "company_id": 2,
      "department_id": 4,
      "reason_id": 2,
      "group_order_id": 4,
      "status": 1,
      "created_by": 4,
      "created": "08.04.2017",
      "modified": "21.04.2017",
      "approved_by": "Kivanc Bey",
      "deleted": null,
      "document_images": [
        {
          "id": 5,
          "document_id": 5,
          "folder_path": "/deneme/2/",
          "file_name": "6.png",
          "created": "11.04.2017",
          "deleted": null
        }
      ],
      "company": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Media Markt",
        "code": "MMM",
        "contact_user_id": 1,
        "manager_id": 4,
        "created_by": 2,
        "created": "16.03.2017",
        "modified": "19.04.2017",
        "deleted": null
      },
      "user": {
        "id": 4,
        "role_id": 11,
        "cell_phone": null,
        "first_name": "Burak",
        "last_name": "Ozturk",
        "created": "16.03.2017",
        "modified": null,
        "token_expire": null,
        "deleted": null
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "description": "Launch",
      "due_date": "16.03.2017",
      "company_id": 1,
      "department_id": 4,
      "reason_id": 4,
      "group_order_id": 5,
      "status": 0,
      "created_by": 4,
      "created": "11.04.2017",
      "modified": "11.04.2017",
      "approved_by": "Kivanc Bey",
      "deleted": null,
      "document_images": [
        {
          "id": 6,
          "document_id": 6,
          "folder_path": "/deneme/2/",
          "file_name": "8.png",
          "created": "11.04.2017",
          "deleted": null
        }
      ],
      "company": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Facebook",
        "code": "FB",
        "contact_user_id": 2,
        "manager_id": 3,
        "created_by": 3,
        "created": "16.03.2017",
        "modified": "27.03.2017",
        "deleted": null
      },
      "user": {
        "id": 4,
        "role_id": 11,
        "cell_phone": null,
        "first_name": "Burak",
        "last_name": "Ozturk",
        "created": "16.03.2017",
        "modified": null,
        "token_expire": null,
        "deleted": null
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "description": "Mert Köksal",
      "due_date": "16.03.2017",
      "company_id": 3,
      "department_id": 10,
      "reason_id": 2,
      "group_order_id": 6,
      "status": 0,
      "created_by": 4,
      "created": "17.04.2017",
      "modified": "17.04.2017",
      "approved_by": "Kivanc Bey",
      "deleted": null,
      "document_images": [],
      "company": {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Google",
        "code": "GGL",
        "contact_user_id": 2,
        "manager_id": 3,
        "created_by": 4,
        "created": "26.03.2017",
        "modified": null,
        "deleted": null
      },
      "user": {
        "id": 4,
        "role_id": 11,
        "cell_phone": null,
        "first_name": "Burak",
        "last_name": "Ozturk",
        "created": "16.03.2017",
        "modified": null,
        "token_expire": null,
        "deleted": null
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "description": "Blabla",
      "due_date": "16.03.2017",
      "company_id": 1,
      "department_id": 10,
      "reason_id": 1,
      "group_order_id": 7,
      "status": 1,
      "created_by": 4,
      "created": "17.04.2017",
      "modified": "20.04.2017",
      "approved_by": "Kivanc Bey",
      "deleted": null,
      "document_images": [
        {
          "id": 37,
          "document_id": 8,
          "folder_path": "/deneme1",
          "file_name": "1.png",
          "created": "17.04.2017",
          "deleted": null
        },
        {
          "id": 38,
          "document_id": 8,
          "folder_path": "/deneme25",
          "file_name": "2.png",
          "created": "17.04.2017",
          "deleted": null
        },
        {
          "id": 39,
          "document_id": 8,
          "folder_path": "/deneme13",
          "file_name": "1.png",
          "created": "17.04.2017",
          "deleted": null
        },
        {
          "id": 40,
          "document_id": 8,
          "folder_path": "/deneme2",
          "file_name": "2.png",
          "created": "17.04.2017",
          "deleted": null
        },
        {
          "id": 47,
          "document_id": 8,
          "folder_path": "/deneme/images/8",
          "file_name": "10.png",
          "created": "19.04.2017",
          "deleted": null
        },
        {
          "id": 48,
          "document_id": 8,
          "folder_path": "/deneme/images/8",
          "file_name": "11.png",
          "created": "19.04.2017",
          "deleted": null
        },
        {
          "id": 49,
          "document_id": 8,
          "folder_path": "/deneme/images/8",
          "file_name": "12.png",
          "created": "19.04.2017",
          "deleted": null
        },
        {
          "id": 50,
          "document_id": 8,
          "folder_path": "/deneme/images/8",
          "file_name": "13.png",
          "created": "19.04.2017",
          "deleted": null
        }
      ],
      "company": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Facebook",
        "code": "FB",
        "contact_user_id": 2,
        "manager_id": 3,
        "created_by": 3,
        "created": "16.03.2017",
        "modified": "27.03.2017",
        "deleted": null
      },
      "user": {
        "id": 4,
        "role_id": 11,
        "cell_phone": null,
        "first_name": "Burak",
        "last_name": "Ozturk",
        "created": "16.03.2017",
        "modified": null,
        "token_expire": null,
        "deleted": null
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 10,
      "description": "Sirket icin yeni masalar alinmistir",
      "due_date": "27.04.2017",
      "company_id": 2,
      "department_id": 3,
      "reason_id": 5,
      "group_order_id": null,
      "status": 1,
      "created_by": 3,
      "created": "19.04.2017",
      "modified": "20.04.2017",
      "approved_by": "Kivanc Bey",
      "deleted": null,
      "document_images": [
        {
          "id": 41,
          "document_id": 10,
          "folder_path": "/home/images/",
          "file_name": "4.png",
          "created": "19.04.2017",
          "deleted": null
        },
        {
          "id": 42,
          "document_id": 10,
          "folder_path": "/home/images/",
          "file_name": "7.png",
          "created": "19.04.2017",
          "deleted": null
        },
        {
          "id": 43,
          "document_id": 10,
          "folder_path": "/home/images/",
          "file_name": "9.png",
          "created": "19.04.2017",
          "deleted": null
        },
        {
          "id": 52,
          "document_id": 10,
          "folder_path": null,
          "file_name": null,
          "created": "20.04.2017",
          "deleted": null
        },
        {
          "id": 53,
          "document_id": 10,
          "folder_path": null,
          "file_name": null,
          "created": "20.04.2017",
          "deleted": null
        },
        {
          "id": 54,
          "document_id": 10,
          "folder_path": null,
          "file_name": null,
          "created": "20.04.2017",
          "deleted": null
        },
        {
          "id": 55,
          "document_id": 10,
          "folder_path": null,
          "file_name": null,
          "created": "20.04.2017",
          "deleted": null
        }
      ],
      "company": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Media Markt",
        "code": "MMM",
        "contact_user_id": 1,
        "manager_id": 4,
        "created_by": 2,
        "created": "16.03.2017",
        "modified": "19.04.2017",
        "deleted": null
      },
      "user": {
        "id": 3,
        "role_id": 10,
        "cell_phone": null,
        "first_name": "Some",
        "last_name": "One",
        "created": "16.03.2017",
        "modified": null,
        "token_expire": null,
        "deleted": null
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 11,
      "description": "Sirket icin yeni masalar alinmistir",
      "due_date": "27.04.2017",
      "company_id": 1,
      "department_id": 2,
      "reason_id": 4,
      "group_order_id": null,
      "status": 0,
      "created_by": 4,
      "created": "20.04.2017",
      "modified": "20.04.2017",
      "approved_by": "Kerem Kaya",
      "deleted": null,
      "document_images": [],
      "company": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Facebook",
        "code": "FB",
        "contact_user_id": 2,
        "manager_id": 3,
        "created_by": 3,
        "created": "16.03.2017",
        "modified": "27.03.2017",
        "deleted": null
      },
      "user": {
        "id": 4,
        "role_id": 11,
        "cell_phone": null,
        "first_name": "Burak",
        "last_name": "Ozturk",
        "created": "16.03.2017",
        "modified": null,
        "token_expire": null,
        "deleted": null
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 12,
      "description": "Sirket icin yeni masalar alinmistir",
      "due_date": "22.04.2017",
      "company_id": 1,
      "department_id": 4,
      "reason_id": 4,
      "group_order_id": null,
      "status": 1,
      "created_by": 4,
      "created": "20.04.2017",
      "modified": "20.04.2017",
      "approved_by": "Kerem Kaya",
      "deleted": null,
      "document_images": [],
      "company": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Facebook",
        "code": "FB",
        "contact_user_id": 2,
        "manager_id": 3,
        "created_by": 3,
        "created": "16.03.2017",
        "modified": "27.03.2017",
        "deleted": null
      },
      "user": {
        "id": 4,
        "role_id": 11,
        "cell_phone": null,
        "first_name": "Burak",
        "last_name": "Ozturk",
        "created": "16.03.2017",
        "modified": null,
        "token_expire": null,
        "deleted": null
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 13,
      "description": "Sirket icin yeni masalar alinmistir",
      "due_date": "19.04.2017",
      "company_id": 2,
      "department_id": 10,
      "reason_id": 4,
      "group_order_id": null,
      "status": 1,
      "created_by": 4,
      "created": "20.04.2017",
      "modified": "20.04.2017",
      "approved_by": "Kerem Kaya",
      "deleted": null,
      "document_images": [],
      "company": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Media Markt",
        "code": "MMM",
        "contact_user_id": 1,
        "manager_id": 4,
        "created_by": 2,
        "created": "16.03.2017",
        "modified": "19.04.2017",
        "deleted": null
      },
      "user": {
        "id": 4,
        "role_id": 11,
        "cell_phone": null,
        "first_name": "Burak",
        "last_name": "Ozturk",
        "created": "16.03.2017",
        "modified": null,
        "token_expire": null,
        "deleted": null
      }
    }
  ],
  "pagination": {
    "page_count": 2,
    "current_page": 1,
    "has_next_page": true,
    "has_prev_page": false,
    "count": 18,
    "limit": null
  }
}
```

Any help would make me really happy. 
Thanks.